# Gradle [META-INF/persistence.xml] was not found

Tags: java, gradle, jpa-2.0

I am building my `JPA`/`EJB` project using `gradle` and getting this warning:

```
$ gradle jar
:compileJava
Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
Note: The persistence xml file [META-INF/persistence.xml] was not found. NO GENERATION will occur!! Please ensure a persistence xml file is available either from the CLASS_OUTPUT directory [META-INF/persistence.xml] or using the eclipselink.persistencexml property to specify its location. 
2 warnings
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
```

My project structure:

```
   ProjectX
   |-src
   |---main
   |-----java
   |-------domain
   |-------ejb
   |-----resources
   |-------META-INF
   |-----------persistence.xml
```

The interesting part is that the persistence.xml ends up in the target jar artifact:

```
$ jar -tf target/projectx.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
domain/
domain/Employee.class
ejb/
ejb/EmployeeEJB.class
META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Why is there complain that the `[META-INF/persistence.xml]` even though it is there?

The gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
project.buildDir = 'target'
sourceSets.all {
    output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir
}
jar{
    destinationDir=project.buildDir
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.ejb:3.0.1','org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.0.0'
}
```

I have quickly tested with maven now and ther is no such warning there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `persistence.xml` is required at compile time. One way to achieve this is:

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
```

Comment: Did not help, I have included the contents of the gradle file.

Comment: Try to add `compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)`.

Comment: This was working for me until I recently upgraded to Gradle 2.13. To fix, I had to remove `compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)` and add `compileJava.doLast { tasks.processResources.execute() }`. Not sure if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the solution suggested by @peter-niederwieser to set your main resources and classes dir to same location results in duplicated entries in your jar archive. Basically, it's twice the original size, don't know if there are other problems.

So to fix this, you have to add

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'
}
```

to your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

META-INF should be in the root of your classpath (/src/main/java/META-INF)

Comment: I followed the documentation and manuals, all indicate that the `persistence.xml` should be in `src/main/resources/META-INF`.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse, if yes, go to project properties -> project facets -> check JPA and configure it. It should generate your persistence.xml.

Comment: Using Intellij and it already discovered the JPA facet. The warning is there when I execute `gradle jar` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The persistence.xml should be in src/main/resources/META-INF. This worked for me. Please not that this was a non spring project